Notification and Workflow Issues in BigCommerce/BundleB2B for Buyer Roles
We are encountering a critical issue within the BigCommerce/BundleB2B that affects our procurement process, specifically involving role-based notifications during the quote approval workflow. We've observed a discrepancy in how notifications are being managed between Junior and Senior Buyers, which could potentially disrupt our operations with a new client onboarding next week.
Observations:

When a Junior Buyer submits a quote, it correctly goes to the Account Manager for approval.
Post-approval, a notification is sent back to the Junior Buyer to proceed with checkout. However, this notification is not being sent to the Senior Buyer who is actually responsible for completing the checkout.
The email for checkout action is redundantly mentioning the Junior Buyer twice in the 'to' field, despite their inability to finalize the purchase.

Expected Workflow:

Junior Buyer submits a quote for approval.
Once approved by the Account Manager, both the Junior and Senior Buyers should receive the notification to proceed with checkout.

Current Issue:
The Senior Buyer does not receive any notification post-quote approval, leading to a breakdown in the intended purchase process.
Steps to Reproduce:

Junior Buyer submits a quote.
Account Manager approves the quote.
Only the Junior Buyer receives an email to proceed with checkout, and no email is sent to the Senior Buyer.

Temporary Workaround:

The Junior Buyer can manually enter the Senior Buyer’s email as a contact when creating a quote. However, this is not ideal as it bypasses automatic notifications and relies on manual updates.

